# Unity linq return matching object

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

I'm playing with the System.Linq in unity and I wonder if this is possible to achieve:

I would like to search a list of RaycastHits and if it contains a hit with a specific component on it I would like to return it instead of the RaycasHit

```
hits.FirstOrDefault(hit => hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>());
```

This returns me a RaycastHit which contains the component Target. I would like to instead get that Target component immediately so I don't have to get component again in a new line

```
RaycastHit target = hits.FirstOrDefault(hit => hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>());

Target combatTarget = target.transform.GetComponent<Target>();
```

Is it possible to cast it or map it in one line ??

Comment: It looks like you're packing enough punch into that functionality that it deserves its own function for best reuse -- it would then not only be 1 line to call, but a simple line at that. You could additionally try make it T generic, so that it allows more than just <Target> passing.

Comment: ``hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>()`` it gives ``target``,and not a condition, why you use it inside a ``FirstOrDefault``. for me use just ``Target combatTarget = hits.FirstOrDefault()?.transform?.GetComponent<Target>();``

Comment: @Sajid this would always only try the `GetComponent` on the first entry in `hits` ... which is not what you want ...

Comment: @derHugo ok I'm glad I'm not the only one who didn't know what they were talking about :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Map it first, then get the first or default:

```
Target = hits
        .Select(hit => hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>())
        .FirstOrDefault(item => item != null);
```

Comment: how about switching ``FirstOrDefault`` and ``Select``, will give the same result and will call the ``GetComponent`` once.

Comment: Btw, I ~think~ this has the same bug as the original code, in that .. it will always return the first hit, even without the component being there, because null ends up in the enumerable.   It should be `FirstOrDefault(item => item != null)`

Comment: i think this ``Target combatTarget = hits.FirstOrDefault()?.transform?.GetComponent<Target>()`` will give the same result and calling the function one time.

Comment: @Sajid Changing the order doesn't matter because linq expressions use deferred execution.   And while your code does what his code does, it doesn't do what he thinks his code does ;)

Comment: @LeoBartkus you are right, calling function inside ``FirstOrDefault`` without testing like it not used, because not return a ``bool``.my proposition will call it one time ;)

Comment: @Sajid Changing the order would break it! Because then you would always try to get the first `hit` which is not `null` (which is always true since it is a struct and therefore would throw a compiler error) and then on this first hit result you would try to find `GetComponent` which might succeed or not! The order absolutely matters! You have to first get all hits that actually **have** the according component. Only **then** you want to get the first of them or `null` if not any was found!

Comment: @LeoBartkus see comment before

Comment: @Ruzihm I guess you could even omit the `item => item!=null` completely. Since the default value for `Component` is `null` anyway I'ld say only `.FirstOrDefault();` should already be enough, right?

Comment: However to be efficient here: This is actually a good example why not to use Linq too often ^^ Here you would anyway have to parse once with `GetComponent` through all `hits`. It would be way better to use e.g. `foreach(var hit in hits){ var target = hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>(); if(target) { return target; } } return null;` it's not a "one-liner" (everything can be in c# as you can see here ^^) but it's the most efficient you will get ;)

Comment: @derHugo linq will not call GetComponent on all hits because linq uses deferred execution.  FirstOrDefault will not ask Select to iterate after it finds its result.  Also please everyone remember that null is not falsey in c#

Comment: @LeoBartkus `null` is not falsey but `UnityEngine.Object` implements an implicit `operator bool` so `if(target)` basically means `if(target != null)` but more then that: even if `UnityEngine.Object` sometimes has a value equal to `null` it actually is not `null` but stores meta data ... using `if(target)` is therefore more secure then using `if(target != null)`.

Comment: @LeoBartkus Still the order is important in Linq .. not for the execution order maybe but for what you are running which query on! `hits.FirstOrDefault(hit => hit != null).Select(hit => hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>());` does: From the `hits` get the first element that is not `null`. On this first `RayCastHit` now run `hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>()` which might succeed or fail. This is totally not what you want. You want `hits.Select(hit => hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>()).FirstOrDefault();` which returns e.g. `null, target1, null, null, target2` and then takes the first valid

Comment: @derhugo correct, also FirstOrDefault() doesn't return another enumerable so changing the order won't even get past the compiler